# Read appended information in text file

Tags: c#

i have a text file that have all information appended, and i want to read that information to a list. Here is design of my text file.

```
------->26/05/2015 17:15:52<------------------
Index :0-0
Index :1-0
Index :2-20150527
Index :3-182431
------->27/05/2015 17:15:52<------------------
Index :0-0
Index :1-0
Index :2-20150527
Index :3-182431
------->28/05/2015 17:15:52<------------------
Index :0-0
Index :1-0
Index :2-20150527
Index :3-182431
```

My question is how can i read that information to my list, I know that i can use line by line but how can i know that i am reading a new item?

Comment: The fact that the line starts with `------->` should tell you it's *a new item.*

Comment: I guess the `------->` shows you a new item was added at the given time? Or is that only a placeholder that something was appended but not content of the file?

Comment: I think you should store somewhere the number of lines read so far. And when you keep monitoring the file just read the new lines.

Comment: That is the information of the new item , but when i am reading that information from the file how can i say in c# languagem that i am reading a new item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we should define word "new" if it means:

- not read so far in previous iterations
- new section in file

Assuming you mean new section in file then you can define such class representing item:

```
class Item
{
    public List<string> Indexes;
    public string Header;

    public Item()
    {
        Indexes= new List<string>();
    }
}
```

And parse the file using simple loop like this:

```
    List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

    var lines = File.ReadAllLines("path-to-file");
    Item currentItem = null;
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        if (line.StartsWith("------->"))
        {
            if (currentItem != null)
            {
                items.Add(currentItem);
            }
            currentItem=new Item();
            currentItem.Header = line;
        }
        else if (currentItem != null)
        {
            currentItem.Indexes.Add(line);
        }
    }
    if (currentItem!=null)
        items.Add(currentItem);
```

If you mean new as not read so far then you should probably store in "Item" class also the date of entry and compare read entry date to those already existing in the collection and read only the new one.

Also you should consider if the file gets cleared (rotates) from time to time, then you must decide if reading whole file makes sense or you should just read from lines which were not read so far using some variable to store the number of lines read in previous iteration. And other things like this.

Answer (score -1):

You will want to use code like this to parse the file.

```
//load the whole file in to memory
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("path-to-file"); //don't forget to add using System.IO;

//you will have to fill in your specific logic
MyCustomObject currentObject = null;
List<MyCustomObject> objects = new List<MyCustomObject>();

//loop over the lines in the file
foreach(var line in lines) {
    if(line.StartsWith("------->")) {
        //header line

        //Again, fill in your logic here
        currentObject = new MyCustomObject();
        currentObject.SetHeader(line);
        objects.Add(currentObject);
    } else {
        //body line

        //double check that the file isn't malformed
        if(currentObject == null) throw new Exception("Missing header record at beginning of file!");

        //process the line
        currentObject.AddLine(line);
    }
}
//done!
```